# When sending java mail from webserver I get gmail.com Suspicious sign-in attempt prevented

Tags: spring, email, gmail

I am using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail`

My Configuration:

```
# ===============================
# SMTP eMail
# ===============================
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=someone@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=non-null-password
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true
spring.mail.properties.smtp.ssl.trust=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

I have been successful sending mail from my Development device,
However once I deploy it on my tomcat server in Dallas,Texas I get this mail from gmail.com that they have blocked my attempt saying the reason that I have sent it from Unrecognized device
I have set the **Less secure app access** on Google Account settings

The thing is I don't have a console or GUI on the server so I cannot verify the device by logging in from the browser

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the  google OAUTH2 documentation.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol

Once you have access to their account, you can send and receive mail on their behalf. Getting users to grant you access to their accounts will be a challenge.

also have a look at the below blog.
http://mydigitalbricks.blogspot.com/2016/03/gmail-oath2-with-spring-and-javamail.html

Comment: I went through my Own Postfix server in the end as The app will require a lot of mails!
Thanx for the help - I will probably revert to OAUTH2 soon as the volume of mails might be large